# Backup SQL Table with php and Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter, backup

I want to backup a table in my database with codeigniter. I found [this Guide](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/utilities.html), and programmed the function accordning to the Guide. The Problem is, that i dont get an error and i can't find the backup anywhere on my Server.

My function looks like this:

```
function backup_Eventtable() {
    $this->load->dbutil();
    $prefs = array(
            'tables'      => array('MYTABLE'),  // Array of tables to backup.
            'ignore'      => array(),           // List of tables to omit from the backup
            'format'      => 'txt',             // gzip, zip, txt
            'filename'    => 'mybackup.sql',    // File name - NEEDED ONLY WITH ZIP FILES
            'add_drop'    => TRUE,              // Whether to add DROP TABLE statements to backup file
            'add_insert'  => TRUE,              // Whether to add INSERT data to backup file
            'newline'     => "\n"               // Newline character used in backup file
          );

    $backup =& $this->dbutil->backup($prefs);
    //I tried it with and without the next 2 Lines.
    $this->load->helper('file');
    write_file('/uploads/EventBackup/mybackup.sql', $backup); 
}
```

I just checked the appache error log and found this line:

```
[Fri Mar 07 14:28:37 2014] [error] [client 192.168.242.116] PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method CI_DB_mysql_driver::backup() in /var/www/html/kaufleuten/admin/system/application/models/eventmodel.php on line 764, referer: http://devzh2.energy.local:8093/admin/events/edit/4002
```

database.php looks like this:

```
$active_group = "default";
$active_record = TRUE;

$db['default']['hostname'] = "localhost";
$db['default']['username'] = "myusername";
$db['default']['password'] = "mypassword";
$db['default']['database'] = "kaufleuten_typo3";
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = "mysql";
$db['default']['dbprefix'] = "";
$db['default']['pconnect'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cachedir'] = "/var/www/html/kaufleuten/admin/cache";
$db['default']['char_set'] = "utf8";
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = "utf8_general_ci";
```

Comment: Have you checked your log file for errors?

Comment: @Pattle I checked the appache error log wich I didn't had checked before. And found the error wich I added to the Question.

Comment: But I just checked it again... and recalling the function doesn't throw the error...

Comment: What does your database.php file look like?

Comment: @Pattle added the information to the Question too..

Comment: Have you autoloaded the database libary? e.g `$autoload['libraries'] = array('database');`

Comment: Yeah i can connect to the database. But I just resolved the Problem.. I noticed that the codeigniter log was disabled. I enabled that one and found an Error there, wich said that it can't open and find the file.. now I had to change the path to the directory to an absolute path and now it works. :) but thanks for your efforts

Comment: No problem.  Glad you figured it out.  If you can post the answer so it may help someone else out in the future

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to enable the Codeigniter Log in the config.php. ($config['log_threshold'] = 2;) There I found the Error Log:

```
ERROR - 2014-03-07 15:33:35 --> Severity: Warning  --> fopen(uploads/EventBackup/mybackup.sql): failed to open stream: No such file or directory /var/www/html/kaufleuten/admin/system/helpers/file_helper.php 90
```

Changing the Path to:

```
 write_file('/var/www/html/kaufleuten/uploads/EventBackup/mybackup.sql', $backup);
```

resolved the Problem.